# Need to build a macro that will take value(table name/form name) from a textbox and open the related table/form in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2007

i want to create a starting form in ACCESS that will hold a Textbox and a button.If user input text(say form name/table name) and click the button,it will show the form/table.If the name is not correct it will show a message.I am new in access.please help me with the macro or other things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table and put the choices.
2. Create a blank form in design view.
3. In this blank form add a text box and a button.
4. Right click the text box, then choose Change To Combo Box
5. View the Combo Box properties
6. From the combo box properties, go to Data Tab
7. Here, you will see Row Source. Click the drop down in the Row Source and select the table where you put your choices.
8. You can Limit users to choose only from the available choices by changing Limit to List from No to Yes.

If you will limit your users from the choices, better not to add the button.